# SFML pollEvent is making pauses when I continuesly press Keys

Tags: c++, sfml

Apparently my pollEvent is making some little pause when I continuously press a Key,

For example if a press and don't release a Key, it's calling the press event, BUT THEN is making a little pause of 0.5sec and only after that starts to call continuously the press Event
So simply put, if I just press a Key and don't release it, it gives me an output like that:

press A

*pause*

press A

press A

press A

press A

. . .

It's kinda problematic for my game.
my pollEvent loop:

```
std::map<_KEYS, bool>   Display::checkEvents()
{
        resetEvents();
        while (_Window.pollEvent(_Event))
        {
            if (_Event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                quit();
            if (_Event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
                if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)) {
                    puts("key up pressed");
                    _Events.at(_KEY_UP) = true;
                }
                if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)) {
                    puts("key down pressed");
                    _Events.at(_KEY_DOWN) = true;
                }
                if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) {
                    puts("key left pressed");
                    _Events.at(_KEY_LEFT ) = true;
                }
                if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)) {
                    puts("key right pressed");
                    _Events.at(_KEY_RIGHT) = true;
            }
        }
        return (_Events);
}
```

Any idea why ? or how I can resolve this problem ?

PS: don't mind my Event map, I think it's really far from being related with the pauses

Comment: Writing to the console takes ages. Maybe those `puts()` calls could be causing it?

Comment: I don't really think, because even if it's takes ages, why does it make a pause only after the first press and then it's smooth? And anyway I put those prints in order to know what were happening, because there was already that pause before them

Comment: That is entirely normal. It's how the OS treat the input. To test, open notepad, type press 'A', and you'll observe the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually I solved it while reading the sfml documentation, for the lazy people, voila :

```
std::map<_KEYS, bool>   Display::checkEvents()
{
    resetEvents();
    while (_Window.pollEvent(_Event))
    {
        if (_Event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            quit();
    }
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)) {
                puts("key up pressed");
                _Events.at(_KEY_UP) = true;
            }
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)) {
                puts("key down pressed");
                _Events.at(_KEY_DOWN) = true;
            }
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) {
                puts("key left pressed");
                _Events.at(_KEY_LEFT ) = true;
            }
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)) {
                puts("key right pressed");
                _Events.at(_KEY_RIGHT) = true;
    return (_Events);
}
```

you need to check the real time input and not the sfml pollEvent's Pool, so check your events outside the pollEvent's While

Thank you for the comments anyway :)